# Django, Docker, collectstatic, UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker

I hope you can help me here. I’m getting a UnicodeEncodeError when running a ‘collectstatic’ in Django 3.0.6. I previously fixed a similar error by setting the locale environment variables LANG and LC_ALL to UTF-8, but this doesn’t seem to work in this case.

My Django project runs in containers (Docker version 18.03.1-ce) and I have just upgraded to Django 3.0.6. Also, in the process, moved to Python 3.6 from Python 2.7. The container is built "FROM python:3.6". Everything works except collectstatic. The static files are stored in an S3 bucket and was all working fine before the upgrade (I had to fix a number of Django things due to the Python upgrade, but all predictable and documented).

The locale settings in the container (with error messages) are:

```
    root# locale
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=en_US:en
    LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

And the message when running collectstatic (from within the container):

```
    root# python manage.py collectstatic

    You have requested to collect static files at the destination
    location as specified in your settings.

    This will overwrite existing files!
    Are you sure you want to do this?

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in                                 execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in         execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in         run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in         execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
        collected = self.collect()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 113, in collect
        handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 338, in copy_file
        if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-        packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 248, in delete_file
        if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 464, in exists
        return self._get_key(name) is not None
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 450, in _get_key
        return self.bucket.get_key(self._encode_name(name))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 193, in get_key
        key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 200, in _get_key_internal
        query_args=query_args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 654, in make_request
        path = self.calling_format.build_path_base(bucket, key)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 98, in         build_path_base
        key = boto.utils.get_utf8_value(key)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/utils.py", line 863, in get_utf8_value
        value = value.encode('utf-8')
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed
```

The Dockerfile snippet:

```
    #FROM ubuntu:14.04
    FROM python:3.6

    MAINTAINER Paul Young
    # Set the locale

    #RUN apt-get -y install locales
    #RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    #    locale-gen
    ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
    ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
    ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python-dev
    RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
    #RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev
    RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

And I am quite sure I have probably missed something very obvious! Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the following from the Dockerfile and re-built the container and for some reason this fixed the problem:

```
    #ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
    #ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
    #ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```